# Print form data in console as object using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have 3 text boxes in html "name, email, comments", i want to print in console as object using jquery but it's not working.

`Object {name: "Ali", email: "ali@gmail.com", message: "hi there"}`

```
<form action="jq_ajax_contact.php" class="ajax" method="post">
        <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"></div>
        <div><textarea name="message" placeholder="Your messsage"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="send"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: $('form.ajax').on('submit', function(){ 
   var that = $(this),
   url = that.attr('action'),
   method = that.attr(method),
   data = {}; 
   
   $(this).find('[name]').each(function(index, value){
       var that = $(this),
           name = that.attr('name'),
           value = that.val();
           data[name] = value;
   });
    console.log(data);
    return false;
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vLgxdvu4/

```
$('form').submit(printObj);

function printObj(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
  var obj = {
    name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
    email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
    message: $('textarea[name=message]').val(),
  }
  console.log(obj);
}
```

HTML without form action submit (in response to comments)

```
    <form class="ajax" >
        <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"></div>
        <div><textarea name="message" placeholder="Your messsage"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="send"></div>
    </form>
```

Comment: it's still not printing in console

Comment: Do you perhaps have your console to only show errors or warnings?

Comment: it is redirecting to php file

Comment: `e.preventDefault()` should stop you from going to the php page.. but you are going to the php page because your action is pointed to `jq_ajax_contact.php` take out the action and method attributes of your form tag

Comment: if preventDefault isn't working it's likely due to other errors thrown that prevent it from even firing and the form gets submitted because of it

Comment: thank you seth McClaine it's working now & thanks all

Answer (score -1):

just make sure you have correct path for jquery file in this tag `<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.8.2.js"></script>`  If you manage that the following is complete working example

```
<form class="ajax" >
        <div><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Your name"></div>
        <div><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Your email"></div>
        <div><textarea name="message" placeholder="Your messsage"></textarea></div>
        <div><input type="submit" value="send"></div>
    </form>



<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
      var obj = {
        name: $('input[name=name]').val(),
        email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
        message: $('textarea[name=message]').val()
      }
      console.log(obj);

alert("printed in console");
    });

</script>
```